# Spring boot Read write Split / Master - Slave / Multiple Databases

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am following this link

https://github.com/kwon37xi/replication-datasource

I have implemented the code But STILL Both my service functions are using the same Database(one which is marked primary)

**Service Class**

```
public class TableService{

    @Autowired
    private Table1Repo t1Repo;
    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public void saveTable1(Table1 t,int a, Table1 t2){
            try{
                t1Repo.save(t2);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Inside");
            }

    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Table1 getTable(int id){
        return t1Repo.findOne(id);
    }


}
```

Then Added two Class(from the link)

ReplicationRoutingDataSource

```
public class ReplicationRoutingDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {

    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        String dataSourceType = TransactionSynchronizationManager.isCurrentTransactionReadOnly() ? "read" : "write";
        return dataSourceType;
    }
}
```

WithRoutingDataSourceConfig

```
@Configuration
public class WithRoutingDataSourceConfig {

    /*@Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")*/
    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="datasource.primary")
    public DataSource writeDataSource() {
       /* EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                .setName("routingWriteDb")
                .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                .setScriptEncoding("UTF-8")
                .addScript("classpath:/writedb.sql");
        return builder.build();*/
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

/*    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")*/
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="datasource.secondary")
    public DataSource readDataSource() {
        /*EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                .setName("routingReadDb")
                .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                .setScriptEncoding("UTF-8")
                .addScript("classpath:/readdb.sql");
        return builder.build();*/
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    /**
     * {@link org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.AbstractRoutingDataSource}는
     * {@link org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean}을 구현하므로,
     * 명시적으로 afterPropertiesSet()메소드를 호출하거나
     * 별도 @Bean으로 만들어 Spring Life Cycle을 타도록 해야 한다.
     */
    @Bean
    public DataSource routingDataSource(@Qualifier("writeDataSource") DataSource writeDataSource, @Qualifier("readDataSource") DataSource readDataSource) {
        ReplicationRoutingDataSource routingDataSource = new ReplicationRoutingDataSource();

        Map<Object, Object> dataSourceMap = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
        dataSourceMap.put("write", writeDataSource);
        dataSourceMap.put("read", readDataSource);
        routingDataSource.setTargetDataSources(dataSourceMap);
        routingDataSource.setDefaultTargetDataSource(writeDataSource);

        return routingDataSource;
    }

    /**
     * {@link org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy}로 감싸서
     * 트랜잭션 동기화가 이루어진 뒤에 실제 커넥션을 확보하도록 해준다.
     *
     * @param routingDataSource
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(@Qualifier("routingDataSource") DataSource routingDataSource) {
        return new LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy(routingDataSource);
    }
}
```

**application.prop file**

```
server.port=8089

spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true

# Primary DataSource configuration
datasource.primary.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/jpa
datasource.primary.username=root
datasource.primary.password=root
# Any of the other Spring supported properties below...

# Secondary DataSource configuration
datasource.secondary.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/jpa2
datasource.secondary.username=root
datasource.secondary.password=root
```

**Repository**

```
public interface Table1Repo extends JpaRepository<Table1, Integer>{}
```

Issue is my both service functions are using the primary Database. What am I missing. I only have these class. Rest I have one Controller

**Edited**
I have made by code work by adding this class

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.example")
public class ReplicationDataSourceApplicationConfig {

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(@Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emfb = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        emfb.setDataSource(dataSource);
        emfb.setPackagesToScan("com.example");        
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        emfb.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);

        return emfb;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslationPostProcessor() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: No error is coming. It is just using the primary database for both read & write.(for both my service functions) but I want it to use diff DB for Read & Write based on annotations

Comment: I met the exact same problem as yours (including the cycle one when I put @primary on top of the LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy. Can you explain more about your solution about why and where we should put those beans? I tried to put them into the same class as the data sources and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the writer of the link you refered.

Which data source do you use with Table1Repo?

You have to inject the specific bean "dataSource" to you JDBC call.

I guess `@Primary` "writeDataSource" is injected to your Repository.

Try to change `@Primary` to "dataSource" or find a way to inject "dataSource" to your repository.

Comment: If I am adding @Primary to dataSource, it is gving me error
The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

  org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration
┌─────┐
|  dataSource defined in class path resource [com/example/WithRoutingDataSourceConfig.class]
↑     ↓
|  routingDataSource defined in class path resource [com/example/WithRoutingDataSourceConfig.class]
↑     ↓
|  writeDataSource defined in class path resource [com/example/WithRoutingDataSourceConfig.class]
↑     ↓
|  dataSourceInitializer

Comment: although I have made the code to work by above code & adding one more configuration class. I have updated my question, Can you please check if its the right way. Also my table1Repo will use both read & write dataSource

Comment: I believe your second solution is ok. But I still don't understand why the datasource configuration is cyclic. It could be a problem of SpringBoot JPA Auto configuration. I use this solution with Spring without any problem.

Comment: KwonNam: I am working on a project & i have a requirement where I hv two different databases & I want read / write split for both? So do I change the code?

Comment: If I want to use read & write in single flow(Call),  how can I do this? What is happening rite now that determineLookUpKey is called only once and not more?

Comment: In Spring boot 2.0.2.RELEASE, on refresh endpoint I am getting error org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindException: Error creating bean with name 'writeDataSource': Could not bind properties to 'HikariDataSource' : prefix=datasource.write, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=true; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 'datasource.write' to javax.sql.DataSource

Comment: It's quite late, but anyway I wrote spring boot example of routing datasource.
you can see here - https://github.com/kwon37xi/replication-datasource-boot
The key configuration is `@Primary` and `@DependsOn`.

Answer (score 1):

you can also try in this way:

[Spring Boot 2 with Multiple DataSource for Postgres Data Replication](https://medium.com/@ehsaniara/spring-boot-2-with-multiple-datasource-for-postgres-data-replication-182c89124f54)

and here is source code in github:

[spring-boot-multi-data-source](https://github.com/ehsaniara/spring-boot-multi-data-source)

The following link explans, how you can have multiple datasource

DB1 (write):

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource-write")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactoryWrite",
        transactionManagerRef = "transactionManagerWrite",
        basePackages = {"com.ehsaniara.multidatasource.repository.writeRepository"}
)
public class DataSourceConfigWrite extends HikariConfig {

    public final static String PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME = "write";

    @Bean
    public HikariDataSource dataSourceWrite() {
        return new HikariDataSource(this);
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryWrite(
            final HikariDataSource dataSourceWrite) {

        return new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean() {{
            setDataSource(dataSourceWrite);
            setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
            setPersistenceUnitName(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
            setPackagesToScan(MODEL_PACKAGE);
            setJpaProperties(JPA_PROPERTIES);
        }};
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManagerWrite(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactoryWrite) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactoryWrite);
    }
}
```

DB2 (read):

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource-read")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactoryRead",
        transactionManagerRef = "transactionManagerRead",
        basePackages = {"com.ehsaniara.multidatasource.repository.readRepository"}
)
public class DataSourceConfigRead extends HikariConfig {

    public final static String PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME = "read";


    @Bean
    public HikariDataSource dataSourceRead() {
        return new HikariDataSource(this);
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryRead(
            final HikariDataSource dataSourceRead) {

        return new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean() {{
            setDataSource(dataSourceRead);
            setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
            setPersistenceUnitName(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
            setPackagesToScan(MODEL_PACKAGE);
            setJpaProperties(JPA_PROPERTIES);
        }};
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManagerRead(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactoryRead) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactoryRead);
    }
}
```