# Spring multiple DB endpoints

Tags: spring, jpa

Is Spring capable of using different database endpoints for failover and query routing - ie, reads go to the read cluster, writes go to the master?  And specifying which endpoint to use per Method in a `Service` class

For example, say we have the following Service. The `save` and `delete` can go to the master endpoint to write, whilst the rest can go to the `read cluster`.

```
@Service
public class ProductService {

    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;
    @Autowired
    private AttributeService attributeService;

    // -------------------------------------------------------------

    private boolean nameAvailable(String name, Long id) {
        if (id == null) {
            return productRepository.findByNameEquals(name) == null;
        } else {
            return productRepository.findByNameEqualsAndIdIsNot(name, id) == null;
        }
    }

    public synchronized void save(Product product, BindingResult result) {
        // synchronized to avoid name duplication
        if (!result.hasErrors()) {
            if (!nameAvailable(product.getName(), product.getId())) {
                result.addError(new FieldError("product", "name", "must be unique"));
            } else {
                productRepository.save(product);
            }
        }
    }

    public void delete(Long id) {
        productRepository.delete(id);
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------

    public Page<Product> getProducts(PageRequest pageRequest) {
        return productRepository.findAll(pageRequest);
    }

    public Product getProduct(Long id) throws ProductNotFoundException {
        Product product = productRepository.findOne(id);
        if (product == null) {
            throw new ProductNotFoundException();
        }
        return product;
    }

    public Page<Attribute> getAttributes(Product product, Pageable pageable) {
        return attributeService.getAttributes(product, pageable);
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont think this is possible (atleast from spring side)

Comment: There’s always a way. I’ll find it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43326808/935122

Answer (score 0):

To quote this answer [stackoverflow.com/a/43326808/935122](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43326808/935122)

The Best Way is to use MySQL Connector/J replication aware driver configuration . Your Connection string will be as below

```
jdbc:mysql:replication://[master host][:port],[slave host 1][:port][,[slave host 2][:port]]...[/[database]]
```

Once you tag a transaction as read only , it will be automatically routed to read only slaves

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-master-slave-replication-connection.html