# Java and hibernate one application separate databases

Tags: java, hibernate, multi-tenant, tapestry

I have been trying to find a solution but with no luck.

I have an Java application (Tapestry) and Hibernate to connect to database. Now there are 3 companies that want to use the same instance of application but different database.

What I have to do is depending on company that accesses the app use different database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to setup Hibernate to read/write to different datasources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386130/how-to-setup-hibernate-to-read-write-to-different-datasources)

Answer (score 0):

You can load different config Files in Hibernate Depending on the company. Just have the Hibernate Config files in Different location per company and configure session from different databases using:

```
File f = new File("C:\\company_name\\hibernate.cfg.xml");

SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure(f).buildSessionFactory();
```

Comment: i tried when user logs in get companyParameter and depending on that load companyParameter+hibernate.cfg file but somehow somewhere on startup still it searches for the default hibernate.cfg
---------------
Configuration cfg = new Configuration().configure(companyParameter+"hibernate.cfg.xml");

Comment: @user3175322 You are passing a String into `configure(string)` method. The expectation is that the String is in classpath. Please pass a `File` parameter as in the example I have given above.